# ORA-00911: invalid character in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WSTAWM (NAZWAM IN VARCHAR2) AS
id_M Miejscowosc.Id_Miejscowosci%TYPE;
 BEGIN

  id_M:=SEQ_MIEJSCOWOSC.nextval;
  INSERT INTO MIEJSCOWOSC VALUES(id_M, NAZWAM);

 END;

call WSTAWM ('Miami');
```

Not done becaue:
ORA-00911: invalid character

Please help.

Comment: Assuming you're using SQL*Plus, shouldn't that be `EXEC WSTAWM('Miami');`?

Comment: @BobJarvis I think we both made the same mistake of thinking about EXEC.  I've never used it before, but `call` is valid syntax.  It's PL/SQL and has nothing to do with SQL*Plus.  I think we'd need more information about the environment to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that the Oracle Client you have installed is 11g and above. Because you cannot assing the nextval to variable in earlier version of oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If you ran everything in SQL*Plus you should have a `/` after the `END;` to let Oracle know to compile the procedure.

Comment: I have compile this procedure. Invalid character still is

Comment: So the problem is with `call WSTAWM ('Miami');`?  The error message should include the line number.  Where are you running that statement?  The `call` syntax will probably only work in SQL*Plus or environments that imitate SQL*Plus.